# Getting Blank Screen when Calling StartActivity()

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-layout, android-manifest

Thanks in advance for your efforts.

I have an Application that revolves around a ListActivity extended class.  Before the app starts, I want to check whether the user is registered, and if not tell him to and get some info from him.  So, I tried to call StartActivity in the OnCreate() method. When that loaded, I got a big black screen.
I thought that it may be related to being run in the OnCreate so I let the Activity start as usual, and I tried to run it in an OnClick event, and I got the same result.
In both cases, if I press escape, that Window goes away and the main app window comes back.

Here are the lines from where I call the new Activity

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(this, EmailAddressGetter.class);
this.startActivity(emailIntent);
```

Here is the code of the class

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.kosherapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * @author Josh
 * 
 */
public class EmailAddressGetter extends Activity {

    public void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.emailinput);
    }

}
```

Here is the emailinput xml contents

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:text="hello"
>
</TextView>
```

And, here is the manifest contents

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.kosherapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0"
>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
    >
        <activity
            android:name=".KosherApp"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        >
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".EmailAddressGetter"
            android:label="email Address Getter"
        >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".GoogleMaps"
            android:label="Google Maps"
        >
        </activity>
        <uses-library
            android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Let me know if there's any other info you may need. Oh, I'm running this with the Google API 2.1-update

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your `TextView` in a `LinearLayout` in `emailinput.xml`?

Comment: yea, I had a normal layout before, but it didn't help. Then I downgraded to something really simple to see if I may have messed something up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change `OnCreate` to `onCreate` in `EmailAddressGetter`.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.emailinput);
}
```

Comment: thanks that was it. Pretty stupid it was something so simple.  I guess I won't make that mistake again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [EditText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html) instead. TextView is for static text which is why nothing is displaying. You should also include the EditText in another layout like Linear or Relative so it looks cleaner.

Comment: Changed to this
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" > <EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:background="#ffffff" android:textColor="#000000" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:text="hello" > </EditText> </LinearLayout>
but it didn't help. While I agree that when this problem is solved, that should be done, that doesn't seem to solve the blank screen problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an intent to call EmailAddressGetter but it doesn't have an intent filter in the manifest. Throw in something like Log.e("EmailAddressGetter", "It worked") in your onCreate and use ddms to see if it is actually opening that activity.

Also, in the updated code in your comment to Robby Pond, remove the xmlns line from EditText